# how to cast/convert enum to another enum in angular

Tags: typescript, enums, angular8

Here is my code:

```js
/**
 * Invoice Type
 */
export enum InvoiceType {
  Instore = 'Instore',
  Marketplace = 'Marketplace'
}
/**
 * Invoice Interface
 */
export interface Invoice {
  invoice_type: InvoiceType,
}
/**
 * OrderType Interface
 */
export enum OrderType {
  Instore = 'Instore',
  Marketplace = 'Marketplace'
}
/**
 * Order Interface
 */
export interface Order {
  order_type: OrderType,
}
```

After I place an order, I need to create an invoice for it.

```js
const invoice: Invoice = {
  invoice_type: order.order_type
}
```

I can't assign a placed order `OrderType` to the invoice `Order` type.

Can I convert/cast `order.order_type` to invoice type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seen as both enums store the same info, just create one enum and reference it twice. See below:

```
export enum OrderLocationType {
Instore = 'Instore',
Marketplace = 'Marketplace'
}
export interface Invoice {
invoice_type: OrderLocationType,
}
export interface Order {
order_type: OrderLocationType,
}
```